# Delete from a dynamic table name in postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have this structure of table, let's call `person`

```
id  | name  | table_name  |oid
----+-------+-------------+---
 1  | James | customer    | 5
 2  | Smith | employe     | 6
```

So what I want is to create a SQL script that allows me delete the row with `id = 5` in the `customer` table before deleting the first row in the `person` table.

This is the first time I am facing this situation, so I have no idea how to do this. I've done several searches on Google but I haven't get any appropriate answer, could anyone help me?

Comment: Are you really still using Postgres 9.1? That has bee out of support for 2 years now. You should plan an upgrade to a supported version as soon as possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a cursor for loop to traverse your table and run a dynamic delete. You may then delete your person table.

```
DO $$
DECLARE
v_rec RECORD;
BEGIN
for v_rec IN ( select table_name, oid from person )
LOOP
  EXECUTE format('DELETE FROM '||v_rec.table_name ||' WHERE id = $1' )  USING v_rec.oid;
END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I would suggest you to change this design if possible.