# PostgreSQL list all tables and DELETE limited rows from each table (loop)

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to select all tables in my PSQL DB and then delete 100 rows from each of them

```sql
-- select all the tables
With table_names as
(SELECT relname FROM pg_stat_user_tables ORDER BY n_live_tup DESC) 
-- delete from each of the tables
DELETE FROM x_table_name WHERE x_table_name IN (SELECT * FROM table_names);
```

This gives me an error:
`Error: relation "x_table_name" does not exist`

and when I add LIMIT 100, to delete only 100 rows, it errors
`Syntax error at or near 'LIMIT'`

How can I correct this query without complicating it?

Comment: This is a duplicate, when the following questions are combined: [Delete from a dynamic table name in postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52489754/delete-from-a-dynamic-table-name-in-postgres)   and [How do I delete a fixed number of rows with sorting in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170546/how-do-i-delete-a-fixed-number-of-rows-with-sorting-in-postgresql)

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```sql
-- select tables names
-- loop through tables names
-- delete a fixed number of rows from each table
DO $$
DECLARE
v_rec RECORD;
BEGIN
for v_rec IN (SELECT schemaname,relname,n_live_tup 
  FROM pg_stat_user_tables 
ORDER BY n_live_tup DESC
LIMIT 100)
LOOP
  EXECUTE format('DELETE FROM '||v_rec.schemaname || '.' ||v_rec.relname ||' WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM '||v_rec.schemaname || '.' ||v_rec.relname ||' LIMIT 100)');
END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Credit goes to the comment by [Luuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/724039/)

Comment: This presupposes `id` is the primary key.  You may want to pull against the constraints table in cases where that is not the case.